# Unknown provider error while injecting service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to inject a custom service to a controller but it give the error that unknown provider. I have attached the relevant code below kindly look in to it as its been a while I am stuck in this problem.I am following coursera's course they are also doing it in the same way but for me its not working.

```
var app = angular.module('tutorial', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial'])
app.service('myService',
    function myService(data) {
        var service = this;
        service.validator = function(data) {
            if (data.name.$valid)
                return true
            else
                return false
        }
        // return service
    }
)
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'myService', myCtrl])
function myCtrl($scope, $http, $location, myService) {
    $scope.editorEnabled = false;
    myService = this;
    $scope.insertemployee = function(empinfo) {
        if (myservice.validator(empinfo)) {
            console.log(empinfo.name) 
            console.log(empinfo.email) 
            console.log(empinfo.address) 
            $http.post('insertEmp.php',{'name':empinfo.name, 'email': empinfo.email, 'address':empinfo.address}).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            })
        }

    }
```

Comment: why are you taking `data` as a parameter to `myService`? you don't have a `data` injectable.  Also, in your controller, you would be overwriting your service anyway with `myService = this;`...

Comment: @Claies is correct. @JC `myCtrl` is correct syntax.